# Python Robot framework Desktop automation winium desktop driver session

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I am using robotframework with python, trying to do desktop automation using appium+Winium.Desktop.Driver.

I am able to launch the application and create driver session, however I am not able to use the same driver session across other python Classes to access the elements on the app.
Getting error when I try to act on the app. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'`

My application is windows desktop application (Windows 10)

Am I missing something here? Please help.
Can anyone suggest best feasible solution.

File:- launchapp.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Resources/DriverFactory.py
Library    ../Resources/SignOnPage.py


*** Test Cases ***
Check whether application is running if not launch the application
    driverfactory
    click on signon button

*** Keywords ***
```

File:- DriverFactory.py

```
from appium import webdriver
import time
from robot.api.deco import keyword

class DriverFactory:
    instance = None

    @staticmethod
    @keyword
    def driverfactory():
        instance = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:9999",
                desired_capabilities={"app": "AbsoultePath_of_My_APP.exe", "args": '-port 345'})
        time.sleep(40)
        return instance
```

File:- SignonPage.py

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from DriverFactory import DriverFactory


class SignOnPage:
    @staticmethod
    @keyword
    def click_on_signon_button():
        DriverFactory.instance.find_element_by_name("Sign On").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying I hate robotframework. I'm currently transitioning my company's  outdated robotframework into pure python. I don't know your circumstance but using python over robotframework may be beneficial, food for thought.

Regarding your question, I think the reason you can't use your click_on_signon_button method (keyword in your robot script) is because you're creating different instances of them. In your robot script you're spinning up a driver from your drivefactory class and your click on signon button keyword is using the drivefactory instance that it imports in your SignonPage.py script.

To fix this, I would suggest moving the drivefactory method to your SignonPage class. Make the drivefactory factory a class method. i.e.

```
def drivefactory(self):
    self.instance = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:9999",
            desired_capabilities={"app": "AbsoultePath_of_My_APP.exe", "args": '-port 345'})
    time.sleep(40) # this seems like a long sleep
```

Also make your click_on_signon_button a class method.

```
def click_on_signon_button(self):
    self.instance.find_element_by_name("Sign On").click()
```

that way you know you are using the same driver instance.

I'm not the best with robotframework (and don't really have the time to look further into this right now) but another option is to pass the driver as an argument to your SignonPage class and initiate a driver for the class, or your could pass the driver as an argument to the click_on_signon_button method.

```
def click_on_signon_button(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_name("Sign On").click()
```

You'll have to lookup the syntax for passing args in robotframework because I don't know it off hand.